# mongodb log message "ctx":"WTCheckpointThread"

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am running the MongoDB server on Linux, all works fine but when I check the log getting the following message.

Can anyone explain why this message occurs! **is it a warning or some bug message**.

```
{"t":{"$date":"2021-07-14T00:36:23.765+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"WTCheckpointThread","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1626222983:765579][126001:0x7f4d57043700], WT_SESSION.checkpoint: [WT_VERB_CHECKPOINT_PROGRESS] saving checkpoint snapshot min: 112435, snapshot max: 112435 snapshot count: 0, oldest timestamp: (0, 0) , meta checkpoint timestamp: (0, 0)"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-07-14T00:37:23.773+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"WTCheckpointThread","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1626223043:773212][126001:0x7f4d57043700], WT_SESSION.checkpoint: [WT_VERB_CHECKPOINT_PROGRESS] saving checkpoint snapshot min: 112441, snapshot max: 112441 snapshot count: 0, oldest timestamp: (0, 0) , meta checkpoint timestamp: (0, 0)"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-07-14T00:38:23.783+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"WTCheckpointThread","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1626223103:783199][126001:0x7f4d57043700], WT_SESSION.checkpoint: [WT_VERB_CHECKPOINT_PROGRESS] saving checkpoint snapshot min: 112447, snapshot max: 112447 snapshot count: 0, oldest timestamp: (0, 0) , meta checkpoint timestamp: (0, 0)"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-07-14T00:39:23.794+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"WTCheckpointThread","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1626223163:794634][126001:0x7f4d57043700], WT_SESSION.checkpoint: [WT_VERB_CHECKPOINT_PROGRESS] saving checkpoint snapshot min: 112453, snapshot max: 112453 snapshot count: 0, oldest timestamp: (0, 0) , meta checkpoint timestamp: (0, 0)"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-07-14T00:40:23.802+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"WTCheckpointThread","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1626223223:802451][126001:0x7f4d57043700], WT_SESSION.checkpoint: [WT_VERB_CHECKPOINT_PROGRESS] saving checkpoint snapshot min: 112460, snapshot max: 112460 snapshot count: 0, oldest timestamp: (0, 0) , meta checkpoint timestamp: (0, 0)"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-07-14T00:41:23.814+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"WTCheckpointThread","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1626223283:814948][126001:0x7f4d57043700], WT_SESSION.checkpoint: [WT_VERB_CHECKPOINT_PROGRESS] saving checkpoint snapshot min: 112466, snapshot max: 112466 snapshot count: 0, oldest timestamp: (0, 0) , meta checkpoint timestamp: (0, 0)"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-07-14T00:42:23.824+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"WTCheckpointThread","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1626223343:824566][126001:0x7f4d57043700], WT_SESSION.checkpoint: [WT_VERB_CHECKPOINT_PROGRESS] saving checkpoint snapshot min: 112471, snapshot max: 112471 snapshot count: 0, oldest timestamp: (0, 0) , meta checkpoint timestamp: (0, 0)"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-07-14T00:43:23.831+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"WTCheckpointThread","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1626223403:831011][126001:0x7f4d57043700], WT_SESSION.checkpoint: [WT_VERB_CHECKPOINT_PROGRESS] saving checkpoint snapshot min: 112477, snapshot max: 112477 snapshot count: 0, oldest timestamp: (0, 0) , meta checkpoint timestamp: (0, 0)"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-07-14T00:44:23.840+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"WTCheckpointThread","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1626223463:840232][126001:0x7f4d57043700], WT_SESSION.checkpoint: [WT_VERB_CHECKPOINT_PROGRESS] saving checkpoint snapshot min: 112483, snapshot max: 112483 snapshot count: 0, oldest timestamp: (0, 0) , meta checkpoint timestamp: (0, 0)"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-07-14T00:45:23.848+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"WTCheckpointThread","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1626223523:848232][126001:0x7f4d57043700], WT_SESSION.checkpoint: [WT_VERB_CHECKPOINT_PROGRESS] saving checkpoint snapshot min: 112490, snapshot max: 112490 snapshot count: 0, oldest timestamp: (0, 0) , meta checkpoint timestamp: (0, 0)"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-07-14T00:46:23.865+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"WTCheckpointThread","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1626223583:865882][126001:0x7f4d57043700], WT_SESSION.checkpoint: [WT_VERB_CHECKPOINT_PROGRESS] saving checkpoint snapshot min: 112496, snapshot max: 112496 snapshot count: 0, oldest timestamp: (0, 0) , meta checkpoint timestamp: (0, 0)"}}
```

Comment: these are just informational logs that you can disable

Answer (score 1):

According to MongoDB's official document, `"s":"I"` means informational.

**MongoDB Log Message - Severity**
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/log-messages/#std-label-log-severity-levels